# Show that $T$ is unitary if and only if we have an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\} \subset V$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$. Show that the set $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ if and only if $T$ is unitary.

I have probably gone into more detail than is really necessary but I'm trying to get my head around all of these ideas.

Suppose $T$ is unitary. So we have that $\langle Tv,Tw \rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$ for any $v,w \in V.$

So $\langle Tv_i,Tv_j \rangle=\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$. Thus we have $n$ orthogonal vectors in a space of dimension $n$ and so we have an orthonormal basis.

Now suppose we have an orthonormal basis. So $\langle Tv_i,Tv_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}.$

Let $v=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,v \rangle v_i$ and let $w=\sum_{j=1}^m \langle v_j,w \rangle v_j.$

$$\langle Tv,Tw \rangle=\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,v \rangle Tv_i, \sum_{j=1}^m \langle v_j,w \rangle Tv_j \rangle = \sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle \langle Tv_i,Tv_j \rangle=\sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle \delta_{ij}=\sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle =\langle v,w \rangle.$$ Thus $T$ is unitary.

Could someone verify if this is correct or not please?

Definition of $v$:

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i$$

Then consider the inner product with $v_i$:

$$\langle v_i,v \rangle =\langle v_i,\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \langle v_i,v \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \delta_{ij}=\lambda_i$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how you define $v$ and $w$. Isn't that a recursive definition? Why is $v$ in the definition of $v$?

Comment: @NobleMushtak I've made an edit discussing where my definition came from.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @NobleMushtak Does it look fine apart from that?

Comment: I think this is basically correct, but why in the calculations in the central part of your post you took the conjugate *of the first variable, not of the second one*?

Comment: @Joanpemo Does it make a difference?

Comment: @NobleMushtak When a basis is *orthonormal*, any vector is written how the asker wrote it after the central "Let". It is one of the biggest advantages of orthonormal basis: one *already* knows what the coefficients in the linear combination of every vector are.

Comment: @Si.0788 Not really for what you want, yet it is a formal difference from the usual definitions in most books I know...in fact, in **all** the books I can remember now.

Comment: @Joanpemo Personally, I learned Linear Algebra online and [my textbook says that it's the conjugate of the first vector in the inner product](http://linear.pugetsound.edu/html/section-O.html#definition-IP). Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're talking about, but at least for this definition, the first vector is conjugated.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Yes, that's right. Look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html , or here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space for what I think it is the more standard definition. But, as already pointed out, it really doesn't matter. Read, for example, here the note in the first page's foot: http://www.math.umd.edu/~hking/Hermitian.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks correct to me except for one thing:

$$\sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle \delta_{ij}=\sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle =\langle v,w \rangle.$$

At this last part, all of the terms where $i \neq j$ are cancelled out by $\delta_{ij}=0$. Thus., the second summation should just be from $i=1$ to $n$, so this is correct:

$$\sum_{i,j} \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_j,w \rangle \delta_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^n \overline {\langle v_i,v \rangle} \langle v_i,w \rangle =\langle v,w \rangle.$$

Other than that, I think this is a really good proof!